# Why does my browser extension only works the first time it's added or when it's reloaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to create a simple extension for Chrome and Firefox which just gets some content from the DOM of certain pages and adds other content.

But the issue is that it only works the first time I load it as a temporary Add-on for testing on both Chrome and Firefox, or when I hit [the extension's reload button on `about:debugging` on Firefox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17UfK.png)

My `manifest.json` only contains the following information:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ft_blackhole",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Shows how many days you have left before you get absorbed by the Blackhole.",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/blackhole.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://profile.intra.42.fr/",
                "https://profile.intra.42.fr/users/*",
                "https://profile.intra.42.fr/users/*/"
            ],
            "js": [
                "ft_blackhole.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "ft_blackhole-0.1@intra.42.fr"
        }
    }
}
```

I use almost the same exact manifest file (same exact matches) for another extension that works and depends on the same URLs. That extension works fine. The difference between it and this one is that while they both insert content in the DOM, my older extension does it after it fetches data from an API, but this one just gets some text from the current page's DOM:

`ft_blackhole.js`:

```js
console.log("Hello World");

let blackholeDiv = document
    .getElementById("bh")
    .getElementsByClassName("emote-bh")[0];

let daysLeft = blackholeDiv.getAttribute("data-original-title");
let daysNum = daysLeft.split(" ")[0];

let status = (() => {
    if (daysNum <= 14)
        return {cat: "", color: "#D8636F"};
    else if (daysNum <= 42)
        return {cat: "", color: "#F0AD4E"};
    else
        return {cat: "", color: "#5CB85C"};
})();

let daysLeftDiv = document.createElement("div");
daysLeftDiv.innerText = daysLeft + ' ' + status["cat"];
daysLeftDiv.style.color = status["color"];
daysLeftDiv.style.fontSize = "0.7em";
daysLeftDiv.style.fontWeight = "400";

blackholeDiv
    .children[1]
    .appendChild(daysLeftDiv);
```

I searched all over the internet, I couldn't understand what is causing it to run only the first time the extension is installed, but then when I refresh the page, it doesn't add anything to the page anymore, until I reload the extension again from `about:debugging`.

I hope someone could help.

**Edit:**

**I also noticed that it also works after a hard reload of the page on Chrome, but not after a normal reload.**

**Edit 2:**

**When I `console.log()` something in the content script, it works all the time, always logs when I reload the page (normal reload), but the other code for DOM manipulation doesn't...**

**Edit 3:**

**I have uploaded a static copy of the profile page if anyone wants to take a look at the HTML content: https://haddi.me/intra-example/intra.html**

**Edit 4:**

It seems the issue is caused after everything is loaded in the DOM, by some javascript that runs after that and makes changes to it, I used Mutation Observer on the target node to log those changes, and there were indeed some few ones, what I can't figure out is how am I supposed to run my code only after that last change (Which is their modification of `span#bh-date`'s style attribute)? This the code I added:

```js
  const blackholeDiv = document
      .getElementById("bh")
      .getElementsByClassName("emote-bh")[0];

  // Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
• const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
      for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
          if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
              console.log('A child node has been added or removed: ', mutation);
          }
          else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
              console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified: ', mutation);
          }
      }
  };

  const config = {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true};
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(blackholeDiv, config);
```

And these are the logs:

[Screenshot from Chrome's Devtools Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXSlH.png)

Comment: I see no permission in your manifest.json file. Try to add the "activeTab" permission. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/

Comment: @user1731468 I tried them and also tried host permissions, but that wasn't the problem, and it makes sense because 1. it does work the first time (without needing the permissions) and 2. my other extensions works without them as well because as I mentioned, the manifest I used there is identical to this one.

Comment: I also just noticed that it also works after a hard reload of the page on Chrome, but not after a normal reload.

Comment: I also noticed now that when I console.log() something in the content script, it works all the time, always logs when I reload the page (normal reload), but the other code for DOM manipulation doesn't...

Comment: You need to use MutationObserver or setTimeout to wait for the DOM content to appear because it's dynamically generated so it happens after the content script runs.

Comment: I did the test here in Google Chrome, with your test page and content script. And I see the cat emoji with the day number, each time I refreshed the web page. See my code in the answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm If I knew the exact dynamic change that happened, is there any other way to run my script exactly after that change? Or would setTimeout be the only solution in this case? (Check out "Edit 4" of my original question)

Comment: There's no universal solution. Use whichever one works for you.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! Tried both with setTimeout and MutationObserver, they both work well but I'll stick with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

In your **manifest.json** file, I do not see a "run_at", to make sure the DOM is ready and then immediately inject the script. Use the "document_end" string in your code.

Source:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#run_time

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Extenstion",
  "description": "Content test!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://haddi.me/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

Tested in Google Chrome web browser version 99.0.4844.83.

Comment: It's right it works on that test page, I tested it now, it works even without the "run_at" and "permissions" properties, but still doesn't work on the main website. Which made me realize that the issue is because even after everything in the DOM is loaded, there is some javascript that runs after it and makes changes to it, I used Mutation Observer to log those changes, please check them out in "Edit 4" of my original question.

Comment: Solved using MutationObserver, thank you!